# Angularjs: jquery selectable

Tags: jquery-ui, angularjs

i have created a directive to handle selectable provided by Jquery

```
mydirectives.directive('uiSelectable', function ($parse) {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            element.selectable({
                stop: function (evt, ui) {
                    var collection = scope.$eval(attrs.docArray)
                    var selected = element.find('div.parent.ui-selected').map(function () {
                        var idx = $(this).index();
                        return { document: collection[idx] }
                    }).get();

                    scope.selectedItems = selected;
                    scope.$apply()
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

to use in html

```
<div class="margin-top-20px"  ui-selectable doc-array="documents">
```

where documents is an array that get returned by server in ajax response.

its working fine i can select multiple items or single item

**Issue**: i want to clear selection on close button

http://plnkr.co/edit/3cSef9h7MeYSM0cgYUIX?p=preview

i can write jquery in controller to remove .ui-selected class but its not recommended approach 
can some one guide me whats the best practice to achieve these type of issue

Update:

i fixed the issue by broadcasting event on cancel and listening it on directive

```
$scope.clearSelection=function() {
      $scope.selectedItems = [];

       $timeout(function () {
            $rootScope.$broadcast('clearselection', '');
        }, 100);
    }
```

and in directive

```
scope.$on('clearselection', function (event, document) {
          element.find('.ui-selected').removeClass('ui-selected')
        });
```

is this the right way of doing it or what is the best practice to solve the issue.

http://plnkr.co/edit/3cSef9h7MeYSM0cgYUIX?p=preview

Comment: https://github.com/willgm/ngSelectable